# How can I set an image as a background of asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

I simply want to set an image as a background of asp.net page. I can display image in simple format on web page, but can't apply it as background.

Answer (score 11):

Use CSS. Add to the theme if you're using one, or a CSS file...

```
body {
  background-image: url(images/image.png);
}
```

Best practices recommend having this in a separate file, rather than the head of the document - and most certainly not inline.

Answer (score 5):

set the background image style for the body element:

```
<body style="background-image:url(bgr.jpg);">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic HTML thing, you need to do some CSS for example such as:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Using db As New MITLibrary.MITLibraryDataContext
                imagelink.NavigateUrl = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(1).FirstOrDefault.Link
                bodyimage.ImageUrl = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(1).FirstOrDefault.image
                bodyimage.ImageUrl = bodyimage.ImageUrl.Replace("~/SystemAssets/", "~/EchoBusV3.0/SystemAssets/")
                lnk1.Attributes.Add("Style", "background:url(" + bodyimage.ImageUrl + ") no-repeat top center; background-size:cover; min-height:280px;")
                lblTitle.Text = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(1).FirstOrDefault.Title
                lblbrief.Text = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(1).FirstOrDefault.Brief
                Lbltitle2.Text = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(2).FirstOrDefault.Title
                Lblbreaf2.Text = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(2).FirstOrDefault.Brief
                HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(2).FirstOrDefault.Link
                Image3.ImageUrl = db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(2).FirstOrDefault.image
                Image3.ImageUrl = Image3.ImageUrl.Replace("~/SystemAssets/", "~/EchoBusV3.0/SystemAssets/")
                lnk2.Attributes.Add("Style", "background:url(" + Image3.ImageUrl + ") no-repeat top center; background-size:cover; min-height:280px;")


                If (db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(1).First.Target = 1) Then

                    imagelink.Target = "_blank"
                Else
                    imagelink.Target = "_parent"
                End If
                If (db.SelectInnerBannerByPID(2).First.Target = 1) Then

                    imagelink.Target = "_blank"
                Else
                    imagelink.Target = "_parent"
                End If

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Comment: You should include an explanation on how this piece of code is helpful for the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
<body background="images/bg4.gif">
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a best practice to use inline styling today. Try using style="background-image:url('yourpath');" or just style="background:url('yourpath');" cause it makes your html more scalable and maintainable